# PHP: Google API: passing referer in header?

Tags: php, http-headers, google-api-php-client, referer

I am trying to use Google's API to consume a YouTube feed, and I have managed to get it working with an unrestricted API key. The problem is, this leaves me open to "quota theft", so I need to restrict my key using "HTTP referrers" restrictions, (as recommended by Google).

I have tried adding all the following as "Website restrictions" in the API control panel:

```
https://*.example.com/*
http://*.example.com/*
https://example.com/*
http://example.com/*
```

But when I make the call from "example.com" I get the following error:

*(403) The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.*

How do I pass the referer value over in the request header?

I am using a code sample taken directly from the API documentation:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('TESTING APP NAME');
$client->setDeveloperKey('AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFg');

// Define service object for making API requests.
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$queryParams = [
    'part' => 'snippet',
    'id' => 'UCQ3f82p5yb6MiA9O1LZbmEA',
    'maxResults' => 10
];

$response = $service->channels->listChannels('id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics', $queryParams);
```

Can someone please tell me how I pass over the referer value with the request?

Explain it to me like I'm 8, lol. ;) Many thanks!

Comment: According to [Google API PHP client docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client), you can [directly control your HTTP request](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#user-content-controlling-http-client-configuration-directly) to add a referrer.

Answer (score 2):

Like you're 8...

You're telling mommy (YouTube) that daddy (your website) needs info. 
When you make the request you need to explicitly say and who's asking for the info.
I had trouble with that same code and decided to use curl to include `CURLOPT_REFERER`.

```
<?php
$videoId = 'oHg5SJYRHA0';   
$apikey = 'INSERT KEY HERE';
$googleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' . $videoId . '&key=' . $apikey . '&part=snippet';

    $HitIt = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($HitIt, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'INSERT YOUR URL HERE');
    curl_setopt($HitIt, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($HitIt, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($HitIt, CURLOPT_URL, $googleApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($HitIt, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($HitIt, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($HitIt, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($HitIt);

    curl_close($HitIt);

    $data = json_decode($response);
    $value = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);

    $title = $value['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
    $description = $value['items'][0]['snippet']['description'];

?>
   <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
   <p><u>Description</u>: <?php echo $description; ?></p>
```